# How to turn a huge live database into a small testing database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, testing, database-migration

I'm currently developing an API for a company that didn't do a very good job on maintaining a good test database with test data. The MySQL database structure is quite big and complicated and the live database should be around 160-200GB.

And because I'm quite lazy and don't want to create test data for all the table from scratch, I was wondering what would be the best way to turn such a big database into a smaller test database that keeps all data with their relationships in a correct form. Is there an easy way to this with some kind of script that checks the database model and knows what kind of data it needs to keep or delete when reducing the database to smaller size?

Or am I doomed and have to go through the tedious task of creating my own test data?

Comment: I have to say having a small tsting database is a BAD idea. Many problems come from things that work well when the dataset is small, but not when they are the size of production. SQL is funny that way. Generate new data yes, but not a smal set, it should be roughly as large as you think the database will be in a year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Jailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer/) which describes itself as a "Database Subsetting and Browsing Tool".  It is specifically designed to select a subset of data, following the database relationships/constraints to include all related rows from linked tables.  To limit the amount of data you export, you can set a WHERE clause on the table you are exporting.

The issue of scrubbing your test data to remove customer data is still there, but this will be easier once you have a smaller subset to work with.

Comment: Oh my god this looks perfect! You just made my day!

Comment: So I got the program set up but stil haven't figured out how I can limit the number of results to let's say 100. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can add a WHERE clause to filter the table you are exporting.  There isn't an explicit way to limit to a specific number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that it doesn't matter how thorough you are the risk of getting live customer details into a test database is too high. What happens if you accidentally email or charge a real customer for something your testing!?

There are a number of products out there such as RedGate's [Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) which will create test data for you based on your schema (there is a free trial I believe so you can check it meets your needs before committing).

Your other alternative? Hire a temp to enter data all day!

ETA: Sorry - I just saw you're looking more at MySQL rather than MSSQL which probably rules out the tool I recommended. A quick google produces [similar results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql%20data%20generator).

Comment: um, SQL is a _language_ (standard) - MySQL is an **implementation** of it.

Comment: Updated - been working with the MS stack too long, MSSQL is the only SQL! ;-)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I guess generating my own data for my needs is the only way. DOOOOOM! This project is getting worse and worse :D

Comment: @Mexxer - it's not that bad, you can cheat some: 1) Change all email addresses to point the companies domain, 2) Create dummy credit card details (if you have tables for those - there should be well-known ones).  3) Swap around keys, so person 1's name ends up with person 3's address, etc.  Heck, you can probably find a _free_ tool to do this (or even just generate dummy data).

Answer (score 2):

In adition to Liath recomend:

maybe its a hard way but u can  just export your schema (no data) and then make a stored procedure to iterate on your (original) tables and make a simple:

```
insert into dest_table (fields) (select * from origin_table where (`external_keys already inserted`) limit 100)
```

or somethink like.

thanks to @Liath : `external_keys already inserted` you hav to make a filter to ensure that any external key of this table already exist on your test database. So you also need to iterate your tables in order by external keys

---

another way its to export your data and edit the sql.dump file to remove the unwanted data (realy hard way)

Comment: You could have RI issues here because of the limits - what if you insert rows where the referenced row hadn't been added?

Comment: Absoluty true, but since we dont know the schema of his database cant make more acutared (ill edit it)